# unable to control android emulator from novnc client in browser (chrome)

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu, vnc, vnc-viewer

I have startup an android emulator with built-in qemu VNC server using following command on OSX lion:

```
$emulator -avd avd_name -qemu -vnc :1
```

after that I want to able to control my emulator through my chrome browser so I find noVNC (https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC)

```
$openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out self.pem -keyout self.pem
$./utils/launch.sh –vnc localhost:5901
```

the result is I can see the screen of android emulator but cannot control the emulator from web browser (I use chrome) , where is the problem?

Comment: noVNC requires username and password how you have giving it ? I am unable view android avd in my chrome browser.